# why my Wishlist showing only one product

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist

In my Magento store when I add a product into wishlist it will replace the old product and add a new one.
I don't know why this is happening.

I have checked all core files in my project.

can anyone know the solution for this?

Comment: It's fresh installation?

Comment: it's not fresh but I didn't change wishlist module

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, you have to override the file

> app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Model/Wishlist.php

find function:
  `public function getItemCollection()`

and change

```
$this->_itemCollection =  Mage::getResourceModel('wishlist/item_collection')
                ->addWishlistFilter($this)
                ->addStoreFilter($this->getSharedStoreIds($currentWebsiteOnly))
                ->setVisibilityFilter();
```

to

```
$this->_itemCollection =  Mage::getResourceModel('wishlist/item_collection')
                ->addWishlistFilter($this)
                ->addStoreFilter($this->getSharedStoreIds($currentWebsiteOnly));
```

this worked for me.